# How to indicate null value but don't connect it in Highcharts Line graph?

Tags: highcharts

I want to indicate presence of null value in the graph.

I thought of replacing null with 0 but then, it would connect with rest of the real data and will draw incorrect graph. Is it possible to not connect zero value with rest of data points?

Alternatively, is it possible to indicate null value using plotband over it like shown in the image?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1fhat8pb/2/)

```
var categoryText= ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

Highcharts.stockChart('container',{

    chart: {
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
    labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return categoryText[this.value];
                }  
            }

    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, null, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, null, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    }]

});
```

[image]

Comment: So, you want to show null values with the orange bars?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi not bars, I was thinking of plotbands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data declared above, then you can try this to include plot bands only for the `null`s. I tried adjusting the offset of each tick to the middle of month but it seems a little inaccurate. Please adjust to your liking. Check out the fiddle.

```
plotBands: data.map(function(item, index) { 
             return { color: 'orange', from: index-0.5, to: index+0.5, data: item }
              }).filter(function(item) { return item.data === null})
           },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/95dLon47/3/